# MySQL should I use WHERE NOT EXISTS?

Tags: mysql, select

Hi, I need to select some users mails and I don't understand how.

I have 3 tables.

**Users**, **payment** and **code**

When one user paid (whithout code), a line is add into **payement** table and we have something like

```
<strong>Payement Table</strong>
+----+--------+--------+--------+
| Id | UserId | Amount | CodeId |
+----+--------+--------+--------+
| 01 |   2545 |     20 |      0 |
+----+--------+--------+--------+
```

If the same user paid with a code now

```
<strong>Payement Table</strong>
+----+--------+--------+--------+
| Id | UserId | Amount | CodeId |
+----+--------+--------+--------+
| 01 | 2545   | 20     | 0      |
| 02 | 2545   | 5      | 42     |
+----+--------+--------+--------+
```

What I want is select all my customers who already paid but not customers who already use the code (CodeId=42 in this case).

So I tried this

```
SELECT mail
  FROM User "
 INNER JOIN payement ON User.id = payement.UserId 
 WHERE payement.CodeId<>42
   AND payement.amount>0
 GROUP BY mail
```

My problem is :

I still have customer who use the code with this request. I think I know why. But should I use WHERE NOT EXISTS ? How ?

Comment: Can you please provide schema of other tables.

Comment: The sql should work fine. It shouldn't return any CodeId with 42.

Comment: @LuudvanKeulen it will also returns Customer with other than 42 CodeId.Means CodeId=0,1,2..,40,41,43,44..

Comment: Only this extra condition is needed `payement.CodeId = 0`.

Answer (score 1):

If a user paid without using code you will have a `codeid = 0`. If so, try:

```
SELECT mail
FROM User
INNER JOIN payement ON User.id = payement.UserId
WHERE payement.CodeId = 0
    AND payement.amount > 0
GROUP BY mail
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use `in` or `not in`clause for multi condition

```
SELECT mail FROM User 
INNER JOIN payement 
ON User.id = payement.UserId 
WHERE payement.CodeId not in (0,42) and payement.amount > 0 GROUP BY mail
```

if you want which customers using code = 0 then

```
SELECT mail FROM User 
INNER JOIN payement 
ON User.id = payement.UserId 
WHERE payement.CodeId in (0) and payement.amount > 0 GROUP BY mail
```

if you want which customers did not using code != 0 then

```
SELECT mail FROM User 
INNER JOIN payement 
ON User.id = payement.UserId 
WHERE payement.CodeId not in (0) and payement.amount > 0 GROUP BY mail
```

Comment: I upvoted to compensate the downvote. If the user who downvoted it will give a solid explanation i'll remove my upvote.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you wish to exclude any user who mentioned code 42, even if that same user has other payments.

Try something like this:

```
SELECT mail, SUM(p.amount) payements
  FROM User 
  LEFT JOIN payement px ON User.id = px.UserId AND px.CodeId = 42
  JOIN payement p ON User.id = p.UserId AND p.CodeId <> 42
 WHERE px.UserID IS NULL
   AND p.amount > 0
 GROUP BY mail
```

Notice the use of the LEFT JOIN / IS NULL pattern to exclude certain rows. That's a commonly used trick to exclude stuff that matches the LEFT JOIN's ON criteria.

Also note the use of the payement table in two separate joins.